# adding css class dynamially in codeigniter pages

Tags: php, css, codeigniter-3

Here is the templating mechanism i am used in my CI application

```
public function index($page = 'login')
    {

        $this->load->view('admin/header',array('page'=>$page));
        $this->load->view('admin/pages/'.$page,$this->data);
        $this->load->view('admin/footer');
    }
```

I need to add a css class to current page ,for that i am using the following way in my header.php file

1.Pass the page name to the header view

and in header.php

```
    <li class="<?php if($page=='admin-home'):echo 'active'; endif; ?>"><a href="<?=base_url()?>home/index/admin-home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if($page=='all-users'):echo 'active'; endif; ?>"><a href="<?=base_url()?>home/index/admin-home">Users</a></li>
```

But i don't its a better way is there any other way to do this efficiently??

Answer (score 0):

If your URLs are like [...]/menu, [...]/home etc you can use easy use JQuery to make it work for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var urlParts = location.href.split('/');
     var urlWithoutLast =  urlParts.slice(0,4).join('/');
     $('a[href="'+urlWithoutLast+'"]').parents('li').addClass('active');
});
```